# How to get Google search result snippets (descriptions) by using importxml function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-search

I want use Google spreadsheet `=importxml` to get Google search results snippets but I don't know what XPath I should use. Could any tell me what is XPath for it?

I tried using `//h3[@class='result-desc']` but it keeps telling me:

> imported content is empty

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=Bmw&safe=off&tbs=qdr:d", "//h3[@class='result-desc']")
```

What is correct XPath for it?

Comment: I use diffrent xpath for title and url but for description i gett error!

Comment: `"//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' rc ')]"` finds the individual search results in Chrome's inspector, but gives the same failure you're seeing in Google Sheets. An incorrectly formatted XPath, `"//div[contains(@class,rc)]"` kind of works in Sheets, but yields more than the search result snippets. (maybe all divs?)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Google Sheets `ImportXML` function will often receive a different HTML than what you see in a browser. (For example it doesn't load JavaScript, etc), so you cannot rely on inspecting HTML to get your XPATHs.

In your case some examples you can try:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=Bmw&safe=off", "//*[@class='g']")`

or

`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.google.com/search?q=Bmw&safe=off","list",9)`